# Regex for price with &nbsp; and comma

Tags: ruby, regex

I have `"8&nbsp;560,90 cur."`. How do I get the whole number `8560` as integer?

I can split it by comma, and then get `[0]` as whole number, asked if there's more way to do it.

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Comment: will there always be non-breaking space literally written as `&nbsp`?

Comment: my questions is for regex

Comment: Yeah, I need to know if it will be literally written as `&nbsp`, if the `;` after is optional, if the there will be floating value after the integer (or is it optional) part and if there will be the `cur.` at the end (or is it optional).

Comment: I just need to get first numbers until comma. and skip nbsp to make it as whole number

Comment: Why do you want to use a regexp?

Comment: How about that for the regex `([\d]+)(&nbsp;)?([\d]+)(.*)` and that for the replacement `$1$3`?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Show us your attempt to solve the problem. Right now it seems like you want us to write code for you, which is not what SO is for.

Comment: My solution is to split by comma and get [/D\/] from [0].
I asked if there's more elegant way. Jordan answered to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
str = "8&nbsp;560,90 cur."
str.gsub(/[^\d,]/, '').to_i
# => 8560
```

This removes every character that isn't a digit or a comma, yielding `"8560,90"`, then calls `to_i` on it, which gives `8560`. This will work for any string as long as you want every digit before the first comma to be part of the number, and none after.

Comment: Nice trick! with converting float to int! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
"8&nbsp;560,90 cur.".scan(/(\d*?).+?(\d+,\d\d)/).flatten.join.to_i
# => 8560
"sdwfdsf560,90 cur.".scan(/(\d*?).+?(\d+,\d\d)/).flatten.join.to_i
# => 560
```

Comment: Yes, this works! But I thought there's a more simple way to do it. Thanks anyway

Comment: what if it has "961,03" without nbsp dividing thouthand ?